# How do you store images for asp.net application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, image, storage

We are just upgrading our ASP.Net shop implementation (from simple one) to structure that should be more flexible. I am just looking for some options how to store images related to product. (there will be two types of images, thumb of the product and then full view images of the product). It should handle at least hundred products.

So far I am thinking about two options:
1) store images in db - images are loaded from Db into stream then into image (displayed by using IHttpHandler)
*Pros*
- The image itself is part of class, business object which we are working with in code behind
- one place to maintain product data
*Cons*
- memory consumption
- traffic increase as we get the product data from other API

2) store images in file system  - images are put in page as link
*Pros*
- none impact on memory as it is not stored in session, app cache.It is used like simple link
- no memory consumption
*Cons*
- needs to keep some name convention for images in File system (perhaps even some folder structure)
- more complicated maintenance of images

Is there any other suitable mechanism? What would you advice to use?

Personally I prefer images in file system, but it can be harder to maintain it as there are two separate places.

Thanks for any comment. X.

BTW: I can really imagine that in some stage the product will also have some videos or any other media that need to be displayed too. In this case Db is not really option, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a system similiar to this. In my opinion, page load speed trumps all other considerations so I went with the 'store images on disk' option.

When images are added to the system, the original image is cropped and resized to the desired display size for browsing and a thumbnail is also generated. Three images are then stored to disk, the original, the display size and the thumbnail. Each one has a GUID generated for its filename.

(Imagine shopping on amazon, when you a browsing a list of products only the thumbnail is visible. When you inspect a product its display size is shown, and you can usually click on the image again to see the full size.)

I had a database table that looked a bit like this.

```
ID                int, PK
FullSizePath      varchar(128)
DisplaySizePath   varchar(128)
ThumbNailPath     varchar(128)
OriginalData      BLOB
```

I kept the original data in the db just incase there was an accident on the file server and the images got deleted, so they could all be re-generated. But this data is never pulled from the db during a page request.

Comment: I have similar opinion. I guess we go in this way.
Just think that to store original image in db is still overkilling as we can use backup, can't we?

Comment: Perhaps. It depends on your backup solution. The files on our webserver arn't backed up, they exist in source control instead. But our database is backed up on a nightly basis, so it made more sense for us to keep the originals in the db like that.

Comment: I recently had to implement a similar api, and this confirmed the plan I was considering. But I didn't think about optimizing the images and creating multiple sizes on the server... that's awesome! Thanks for the great idea!

Answer (score 1):

i think mixture of both is the best,
for small critical image db is preferable
and for large in amount and size file system is better

Comment: I thing that mixing both way can cause more troubles then advantages. It's just simple argument that you need to cover more places, sources.Thanks for comment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have covered anything. You can store the main image in filesystem/db but you can generate the thumbnails on the fly programatically, which would reduce some disk space.

Answer (score 0):

In instances like your example, where I work we tend to store the images on the disk, and then keep a record of the filename in the db.

Then when you have a db of your products, you can look up and dynamically load your image per product.

This also is quite nice if you have an admin system for adding/removing/editing products.

I suppose it's kind of in between your two original suggestions, you can even store all the images in the same directory this way if you like.

Comment: What convention are using for the names? (Guid, or productname + index + suffix, prefix?)
Did you run into some problems with lost linking? Or perhaps some other issues?

Comment: We have an image table containing filename and an ID (plus sometimes other info like width & height), so all images are referred to by ID in things like stored procedures. 

Naming of the images themselves, we prefix all thumbnails with small_ but otherwise leave the filenames unchanged - for products they are all added though an admin system, the image uploading portion of which checks for duplicates.

You're correct in that it might be nicer to add the product guid to the image file name too, but we don't do that. running an sp against a product can retrieve filenames of linked images.

Comment: (sorry, walloftext!) Lost links hasn't been an issue for us, but I can imagine it might occur in instances where you're moving databases or reset ID's in a table or something.

Works quite well in practice, the weakest link for us is the component we use for the image upload & resize itself!


Where all the product images are in the same image folder, we can keep the path in the webconfig too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL 2008, you have an option for the [FILESTREAM feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx).

Here's the gist, but you should read the whole white paper:

> FILESTREAM is a new feature in the SQL
>   Server 2008 release. It allows
>   structured data to be stored in the
>   database and associated unstructured
>   (i.e., BLOB) data to be stored
>   directly in the NTFS file system. You
>   can then access the BLOB data through
>   the high-performance Win32® streaming
>   APIs, rather than having to pay the
>   performance penalty of accessing BLOB
>   data through SQL Server.
>
> FILESTREAM maintains transactional
>   consistency between the structured and
>   unstructured data at all times, even
>   allowing point-in-time recovery of
>   FILESTREAM data using log backups.
>   Consistency is maintained
>   automatically by SQL Server and does
>   not require any custom logic in the
>   application. The FILESTREAM mechanism
>   does this by maintaining the
>   equivalent of a database transaction
>   log, which has many of the same
>   management requirements (described in
>   more details in the “Configuring
>   FILESTREAM Garbage Collection” section
>   later in this white paper). The
>   combination of the database’s
>   transaction log along with the
>   FILESTREAM transaction log allows the
>   FILESTREAM and structured data to be
>   transactionally recovered correctly.